# How do I avoid the "USB Accessories Disabled" notification when charging devices from thunderbolt dock & monitor?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, charging, power

I've got a brand-new TS4 thunderbolt dock with tons of high-wattage ports, happily charging my M1 Max macbook at 98W. It charges super fast over the single cable, as well as driving the display and all the peripherals. This seems like living the dream, in terms of power delivery.

However, when I plug in certain basic charging accessories (for example, the charging port of a power bank, an apple watch charger, a magsafe charger) to its nominally "high-wattage" USB charging ports, or to the USB ports on the monitor plugged into it (an LG 38WN95C-W), I get endless messages telling me that the USB device is using too much power.  As far as I can tell, no other ill effects are occurring; it just resets the one port that is drawing too much power, it doesn't shut off anything else; the battery or device keeps charging, just perhaps slightly more slowly than it would otherwise since there are periodic power cuts each time macOS thinks there's a problem.  I can also plug in devices that draw plenty of power (external SSDs, cameras, glowy LED keyboards & mice) with no such warning.

Is this a CalDigit problem, an LG problem, an Apple problem, or all of the above?

Comment: Wow, so much empty :( I also get the annoying pop-up but no other issues - all my USB devices are still working and my phone is charging nicely - it's only the pop-up that's really annoying.

Comment: @mjaggard I just answered the question below; a TS4 firmware update fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently a CalDigit problem, and after applying the just-released [“TS4 Power Delivery Firmware Update for USB-C Connected Monitors”](https://www.reddit.com/user/CalDigitDalton/comments/145c3vn/ts4_power_delivery_firmware_update_for_usbc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf&utm_content=1&utm_term=22), the issue has been resolved.